# Dynamic edge color for sigmajs

Tags: javascript, svg, force-layout, sigma.js

I am trying to apply custom colors to the edges dynamically and update the graph in sigmajs
The canvas and the webgl renderers work fine, but the svg renderer does not work. It takes the default value of the edge color.

This is the link to the library: https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js

Can someone point out to me if there is any extra config required?

my code will be something like this:

```
$.each(s.graph.edges(), function(index, edge) {
  edge.color = '#f00';
});
```

i am using forceAtlas2 plugin with this to do the layout: https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/master/plugins/sigma.layout.forceAtlas2

This color change works fine for canvas and webgl but not for svg. I need svg to work as the canvas is low resolution and webgl does not support curved edges. Any other help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using sigmajs master code, or the last release ?

Ok stupid question, there is no SVG render on the 1.0.3 ..

I have try this code, and it's working on my firefox : http://embed.plnkr.co/Rvgzjq5vor97lFKNl1vj/preview

```
    <!-- START SIGMA IMPORTS -->
<script src="../src/sigma.core.js"></script>
<script src="../src/conrad.js"></script>
<script src="../src/utils/sigma.utils.js"></script>
<script src="../src/utils/sigma.polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="../src/sigma.settings.js"></script>
<script src="../src/classes/sigma.classes.dispatcher.js"></script>
<script src="../src/classes/sigma.classes.configurable.js"></script>
<script src="../src/classes/sigma.classes.graph.js"></script>
<script src="../src/classes/sigma.classes.camera.js"></script>
<script src="../src/classes/sigma.classes.quad.js"></script>
<script src="../src/classes/sigma.classes.edgequad.js"></script>
<script src="../src/captors/sigma.captors.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="../src/captors/sigma.captors.touch.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/sigma.renderers.canvas.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/sigma.renderers.webgl.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/sigma.renderers.svg.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/sigma.renderers.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/webgl/sigma.webgl.nodes.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/webgl/sigma.webgl.nodes.fast.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/webgl/sigma.webgl.edges.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/webgl/sigma.webgl.edges.fast.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/webgl/sigma.webgl.edges.arrow.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.labels.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.hovers.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.nodes.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.curve.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.arrow.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edges.curvedArrow.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edgehovers.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edgehovers.curve.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edgehovers.arrow.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.edgehovers.curvedArrow.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/canvas/sigma.canvas.extremities.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/svg/sigma.svg.utils.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/svg/sigma.svg.nodes.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/svg/sigma.svg.edges.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/svg/sigma.svg.edges.curve.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/svg/sigma.svg.labels.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/renderers/svg/sigma.svg.hovers.def.js"></script>
<script src="../src/middlewares/sigma.middlewares.rescale.js"></script>
<script src="../src/middlewares/sigma.middlewares.copy.js"></script>
<script src="../src/misc/sigma.misc.animation.js"></script>
<script src="../src/misc/sigma.misc.bindEvents.js"></script>
<script src="../src/misc/sigma.misc.bindDOMEvents.js"></script>
<script src="../src/misc/sigma.misc.drawHovers.js"></script>
<!-- END SIGMA IMPORTS -->
<script src="../plugins/sigma.plugins.neighborhoods/sigma.plugins.neighborhoods.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/sigma.layout.forceAtlas2/supervisor.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/sigma.layout.forceAtlas2/worker.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <style>
    #graph-container {
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #455660;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="graph-container"></div>
</div>
<script>
/**
 * This is a basic example of how one could spawn a freestyle svg renderer
 * to achieve his/her goal through css and jQuery to display fancy graphs
 * but somewhat less performant.
 */
var i,
    s,
    N = 100,
    E = 500,
    g = {
      nodes: [],
      edges: []
    };

// Generate a random graph:
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  g.nodes.push({
    id: 'n' + i,
    label: 'Node ' + i,
    x: Math.random(),
    y: Math.random(),
    size: Math.random(),
    color: '#666'
  });

for (i = 0; i < E; i++)
  g.edges.push({
    id: 'e' + i,
    source: 'n' + (Math.random() * N | 0),
    target: 'n' + (Math.random() * N | 0),
    size: Math.random(),
    color: 'red'
  });

// Instantiate sigma:
s = new sigma({
  graph: g,
  settings: {
    enableHovering: false
  }
});

s.addRenderer({
  id: 'main',
  type: 'svg',
  container: document.getElementById('graph-container')
});

s.refresh();

</script>
```

Comment: master. i rasied an issue there. they said they will look into it. its an issue :)

Comment: Here is the link to the github issue for reference : https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/issues/575

Comment: @logisma yeah, thats me who raise it. had a look :)